# How to include typescript class in node.js app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

What's the best way to include typescript class definition in node.js file?

Let's say I have this code:

```
class Car{
    public Color;

    constructor(aColor:string){
        this.Color = aColor;
    }
}
```

I want to be able to make an instance of a Car this way:

```
var MyCar = new Car("green");
```

I know that require() will return an object, but I dont need an object I only need to know the definition of a Car.

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: The easiest way to make your class(es) visible is to [define a module](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Handbook#modules), but I'm not sure how you commonjsify the result. `module.exports = MyModule` I guess?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in `car.ts`:

```
class Car{
    public Color;

    constructor(aColor:string){
        this.Color = aColor;
    }
}
export = Car;
```

in some other file:

```
import Car = require('./car');
var MyCar = new Car("green");
```

Compile both files with `--module commonjs`.

More about external modules : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KDrWLMUY0R0&hd=1